# Where is my .git/refs/heads/master file

Tags: git

I am following below article to get some idea of internals of git.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References

It says that git stores references to latest commit objects of each branch in `.git/refs/heads` directory.

In one of my git repositories, I found that there's nothing in `.git/refs/heads` directory. All other repositories I checked contain files for each branch in the repository.

This repository with empty `.git/refs/heads` actually has a master branch and it works perfectly.

Can someone explain why`.git/refs/heads` is empty and how git works without a problem in this condition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Then there's going to be a file named `.git/packed-refs` there too.  When repository histories start getting really long, having hundreds of tags  starts to slow things down, so [`git pack-refs`](ftp://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pack-refs.html)  will put them all in the `packed-refs` file.

Yay for going after the internals, you're going to be floored by how simple it is.  It's usually worthwhile reading whatever docs come with a tool, you're in [`repository layout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrepository-layout.html) and [core commands](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitcore-tutorial.html) territory, plus, see the "see also" links at the bottom.  You should also be able to get those with `git help`, I hope there's no distribution that omits the docs.

Answer (score 0):

If the repository has no commits yet then `.git/refs/heads` can be empty (and `.git/packed-refs` may not exist). This makes sense since there is no commit hash to be entered into any ref file yet.