# Git repository is on the master branch, but has no master ref

Tags: git

I just came across this in one of my git repos due to a failure in a script of mine. I thought that every branch head, including master, had a corresponding ref. That's true in most of my repos, but I have two of them that don't.

`git branch` says `* master` and two tracking branches

but `.git/refs/heads` is empty

So I obviously misunderstand what the heads refs are for. My config has master in it

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

but that `refs/heads/master` isn't there.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Does "refs/remotes/origin/master" exist? That would be the locally maintained version of "refs/heads/master" on origin

Comment: Yes, that is there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is my .git/refs/heads/master file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141219/where-is-my-git-refs-heads-master-file)

Answer (score 1):

For optimization reasons, sometimes git packs the references in `.git/packed-refs` in the format:

```
e220b43404aca15574c7a9be3724a40587093414 refs/heads/master
```

Once you change the value for the reference, it will create back a `.git/refs/heads/master` file (until the next packing).

Comment: mbg@phobos:/u/mbg/mitel-msl-tug$ cat .git/packed-refs  | grep master
eceb784e79a4db5908fa180112abbf1ce2513bb4 refs/heads/master
08f478ad369d68b5bd33e8b425eb5e282e8e64ae refs/remotes/bitbucket/master
eceb784e79a4db5908fa180112abbf1ce2513bb4 refs/remotes/origin/master
fa3a54dbbd6db4df538723b6232eb281ec0ff5a1 refs/remotes/pub/master

Comment: So yes, that's where it is.

Comment: (`grep master .git/packed-refs` is shorter and lighter). Feel free to mark the question as answered.