# Git internals: why `.git/refs/remotes/origin/` doesn't have all branches

Tags: git

Doing `ls .git/refs/remotes/origin/`, I see only a subset of the remote `origin`'s branches. Why is that? `git branch -a` have all the branches, so I fetched them properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is my .git/refs/heads/master file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141219/where-is-my-git-refs-heads-master-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git stores references in two forms, which it does not specifically name, but by analogy to packed objects, and the fact that the second form of reference is a file named `.git/packed-refs`, we could call *loose* and *packed*.

The individual files in `.git/refs/` are, in effect, *loose* references, with the packed ones in `.git/packed-refs`.  Unlike objects, if there is a loose version of a reference, it may differ from the packed version: the loose one is considered the correct value.  This means there is no need to delete the packed one when changing the value of a loose reference.

You are not supposed to know or care about all of this: to read the value of a reference, use `git rev-parse` (for non-symbolic references) or `git symbolic-ref` (for symbolic references like `HEAD`).  To update them, use `git update-ref` or `git symbolic-ref`.  These commands take care of the required locking.