# Why are not all references listed in the .git/FETCH_HEAD file listed in my .git/ref folder?

Tags: git

My git config file specifies the following refspec for origin:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/rschmidtner/*:refs/remotes/origin/rschmidtner/*
```

`git ls-remote --heads | grep rschmidtner` shows me six branches. These branches are also listed in the `.git/FETCH_HEAD` file.

Why does `.git/refs/remotes/origin/rschmidtner` only contain three references, even after I fetched via `git fetch origin`?

Comment: What does `git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin` or `git branch -r` produce?

Comment: Both list 6 references starting with `rschmidtner`

Comment: So, as you can see, some names aren't stored as *files*. In the future, you might find that *no* branch names are stored as files, or at least fewer names are stored as files, depending on OS and other preferences. Don't rely on the file names existing.

Comment: How does git know what commit to check out when I do `git checkout branch_name_that_is_not_a_file_name_under_refs`?

Comment: @zwithouta : to add to torek's comment : git also stores references in the `.git/packed-refs` file. In the current git implementation, it is a simple text file : run `cat .git/packed-refs` and you'll quickly understand how it's laid out.

Comment: `git for-each-ref` is a documented command part of the public `git` API, so you can rely on its behavior being correct. The fact that references are stored as individual files under `.git/refs` or as lines in `.git/packed-refs`, on the other hand, is part of the internal implementation, and may change in the future (there already was an evolution from "individual files only" to `.git/packed-refs`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30143136/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+.git%2Frefs%2Fheads%2Fmaster+file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that refs are no longer always stored individually in files.

Git's original design did exactly that: a regular reference, such as a branch name or remote-tracking name, was just a file *in* the `refs/` directory.  If `refs/heads/master` existed, it was a file containing one hash ID, and hence that hash ID was the tip commit of the `master` branch.  When remotes and remote-tracking names were invented, `refs/remotes/origin` would contain directories and/or files as needed to hold names like `refs/remotes/origin/rschmidtner/foo`.

This stuff still exists, but it has several drawbacks:

- Repositories with tens of thousands of tags (Chromium, for instance) cause bad behavior (such as "use up all the inodes") if the tags are stored this way.
- On typical Windows and macOS systems, a branch named `fred` and a branch named `Fred` become conflated, even though Git itself *assumes* these are two different branch names—and they *are* on Linux servers.
- Last—although there's an intent to preserve this for the indefinite future, to avoid creating problems for *older* Git versions—this means that it is impossible, for instance, to have branches named `hello` *and* `hello/world` at the same time: this would require the file system to store both a *file* named `refs/heads/hello` and a *directory* named `refs/heads/hello` containing a file named `world`.

  This particular issue combines with the case-folding issue (second bullet point) when someone creates `refs/heads/fred`, then decides to add `refs/heads/Fred/one`, `refs/heads/Fred/two`, and so on, on their Linux system.  It works great there, and causes misery in case-folding land.

*Current* versions of Git therefore store ref names in a hybrid fashion: there is a file in `.git` named `packed-refs` that contains newline-terminated lines, each of which lists a ref or "peeled ref" name and hash ID.  The peeled value is useful with tags, which often point to tag objects that in turn point to commits: this way Git can find the commit instantly, without having to indirect through one or more tag objects.  (The peeled variant is indicated by a suffix, `^{}`.)  If a packed ref exists for ref *R*, and an unpacked file exists for the same ref *R*, the unpacked file overrides the packed ref: in this way, Git can leave the packed-refs file alone when it updates a branch name, for instance.

*Future* versions of Git are likely to have a real refs database, rather than this rather cheesy flat-file "database" named `packed-refs`.  When that happens, even the act of updating a ref won't create a file-system-level file.  This will neatly solve all the listed drawbacks, while creating one new drawback: namely, you won't be able to just create files any more.

#### So how do I find my refs?

Use the prescribed API: `git for-each-ref` for listing while reading the values programmatically, `git branch` and `git tag` for viewing them as a human.  Use `git symbolic-ref` to read or write individual symbolic refs—currently this means `HEAD` and `refs/remotes/remote/HEAD` only<sup>1</sup>—and `git update-ref` to change the value stored in one or more refs.  Use `git rev-parse` to read a specific ref's value; pay close attention to [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) here as there is a lot of helpful stuff you can have Git do for you *during* the rev-parse operation.

*Don't* depend on the files existing, as they already don't in some cases.

---

<sup>1</sup>A symbolic ref is a reference containing the *name of another reference*.  Git originally did this just for `HEAD`, by making it a symbolic link.  Since symlinks don't exist on some systems, Git had to adapt by changing this to a file containing the name of another ref.  The Git source code for dealing with these has long been slightly squirrelly as a result, and if you made a normal-looking ref name that was a symbolic ref, it would occasionally misbehave.  For example, deleting a branch named `indir` that was really a symbolic ref to a branch named `b` would delete branch `b` rather than `indir`.

Some of these oddities have been fixed, but unless you plan to find and fix the rest of them, it's wisest to avoid symbolic refs other than those directly supported by Git, i.e., the special `HEAD` names.

Comment: I found that absolutely fascinating. It tied together a bunch of stuff I'd wondered about.