How do I check jgit setCloneAllBranches() clones all branches to my local
I am trying to clone a git repository into my local using the following code:
repo = Git.cloneRepository()
.setCloneAllBranches(true)
.setBranch(branch)
.setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(userName, pwd))
.setURI(uri)
.setDirectory(new File(toDir))
.call()

But I am unable to see .git/refs/remotes folder in my local, though I am able to see .git/refs/heads how do I confirm that it indeed clones all the branches.
I am also trying to print all my local branches using
Git git = Git.open(new File(toDir));

List<Ref> branches = git.branchList().call();

System.out.println("Local branches:");
for (Ref branch : branches) {
     System.out.println(branch.getName());
}

With this also I am not able to see other branches being cloned.
I believe there should be .git/refs/remotes/origin folder with all my branches.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30143136/7976758 .git/refs/heads and .git/refs/remotes/origin can be empty because they packed into .git/packed-refs. Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22refs%2Fheads%22+empty

Do not check or edit files under .git/. Use git commands. git branch --all in your case. I don't know how to translate it into JGit parlance.
